# Append related items to newform.aspx

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part

I have a master list that creates an ID for each new item, using a Calculated column. For example, "15-0727".

On the master list's newform.aspx page, I have included a button to create subtasks, which are created and stored on a separate list. Each subtask has the same master ID number included on it as a calculated column.

I would like for each subtask to append to the master list newform.aspx page, as they are being created. So, master master list details on top, supporting tasks listed on the bottom.

I cannot figure out how to create a filter to only display items that share the common ID number.

I suspect there has to be a way to do this in Designer. I am not a strong programmer and I do not have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by your tag that you're looking to do this in SharePoint 2010.. If that's the case, there's an excellent article by Mark Rackley that explains how to do what you're looking for, which is commonly called a parent/child list relationship.

I use this method all the time and couldn't imagine a lot of my projects without this.

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx